# Ruby on Rails Interating through associated collectionproxy and updating attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have two models associated with each other.

For example an Order contains many Order Items.

If there is a match (ie: already an order item with the same sku), I'd like to increment an order item quantity. Is this the best way to do it in Ruby?

```
switch = false
order.order_items.each do |item|
   if item.sku == test.sku
     item.increment!(:quantity)
     switch = true
  end 
end
```

I was originally trying to do something like:

```
if order.order_items.where(sku: test.sku).length > 0
  order_item = order.order_items.where("sku = ?", test.sku).take
  order_item.increment!(:quantity)
end
```

but I ended up having some errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using one query without fetching the data and iterating through it, as below:

```
order.order_items.where(sku: test.sku).update_all("quantity = quantity + 1")
```

**NB:**
`update_all` skip the validation & callbacks

Comment: You might want to specify the the table with `"order_items.quantity = order_items.quantity + 1"`  to avoid any potential ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. Will try this out.